# Convert query to hibernate criteria query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, postgresql, sybase, hibernate-criteria

I have the following Sybase query,

```
select *
  from dbo.translation_style_sheet t1
 where t1.create_date = (select max(t2.create_date) 
                           from dbo.translation_style_sheet t2
                          where t1.file_name = t2.file_name);
```

I'm trying to convert it to a hibernate criteria query, but haven't been able to figure it out. I'm assuming I need to use a DetachedCriteria to handle this, but not sure how to work with it.

This is what I have thus far.

```
DetachedCriteria maxCreateDate = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TranslationStyleSheet.class, "translationStyleSheet2")
    .setProjection( Property.forName("createDate").max() )
    .add( Property.forName("translationStyleSheet2.fileName").eqProperty("translationStyleSheet.fileName") );

List<TranslationStyleSheet> translationStyleSheets = this.session.createCriteria(TranslationStyleSheet.class, "translationStyleSheet")
            .add( Property.forName("createDate").eq(maxCreateDate))
            .list();
```

I'm getting the following exception.

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException
could not execute query

SQL
    select this_.translation_style_sheet_id as translat1_20_0_, this_.create_date as create2_20_0_, this_.description as descript3_20_0_, this_.file_content as file4_20_0_, this_.file_extension as file5_20_0_, this_.file_name as file6_20_0_, this_.file_size as file7_20_0_, this_.style_sheet_content as style8_20_0_, this_.style_sheet_type as style9_20_0_ from translation_style_sheet this_ where this_.create_date = (select max(translationStyleSheet2_.create_date) as y0_ from translation_style_sheet translationStyleSheet2_ where translationStyleSheet2_.file_name=this_.file_name)
SQLState
    ZZZZZ
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The error seems to be be happening at the max(translationStyleSheet2_.create_date) as y0_
as. When I remove the as y0_ in the sql statement, I'm able to run the query the query, however I'm not sure how to repair this in hibernate criteria though.

Comment: Why the PostgreSQL and MySQL tags?

Comment: @Craig Ringer, I don't believe this problem is directly related to the type of database, but rather hibernate. My assumption is anybody using any of these databases with hibernate would be able to help me resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

So I had no success getting this to work as a criteria query, but I did have success getting it to work as an HQL query.

HQL solution

```
this.session.createQuery("from TranslationStyleSheet this "
                + "where this.createDate = (select max(translationStyleSheet2.createDate) "
                + "from TranslationStyleSheet translationStyleSheet2 "
                + "where translationStyleSheet2.fileName=this.fileName)")
                .list();
```

I'm still interested in getting the query to work as a criteria query though.